# How to clear physical keyboard buffer when activity starts

Tags: android

I want to clear the physical keys when my activity starts. I have an activity that opens another activity when the user clicks Enter on an EditText. The function checkAnswer() below will show a new activity. It works fine with soft keys. But with the physical key, the unwanted enter is sent to the new activity.

I guess that because the new activity is called before onEditorAction() returns true - so Android system thinks that my handler does not consume the enter, and it sends the entry to the new activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event==null) {
        if ((actionId != EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) && (actionId != EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {}
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    checkAnswer();
    return true;
}
```

Just want to clear the key buffer when the new activity starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
  View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
  //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window 
 token from it
 if (view == null) {
    view = new View(activity);
 }
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I still want to use the keyboard in the new activity, I just don't want to received unwanted enter which is pressed in the caller.